# ASP.NET Core 6 Web API & IIS 10 - Not Found

Tags: localhost, hosting, .net-6.0, iis-10, windows-server-2019

I am trying to deploy my ASP.NET Core 6 Web API on IIS on a Windows Server 2019 machine. The end goal is to only call my API on `localhost:port/swagger` or `localhost:port/{controller}/{action}` from that server (and not from the outside).

Here is what I have so far:

1. Published the API using the following command: `dotnet publish --configuration Release`
2. I have Microsoft .NET 6.0.14 - Windows Server Hosting installed
3. I have enabled `Directory Browsing`
4. I added a new site in IIS, and pointed the physical path to a folder where I pasted the published output:
5. Configured the binding to `http`, IP address Àll Unassigned`, and port` 8080`

When I click on Browse, it takes me to the URL `localhost:8080`, and I get the list of files that are in the physical path, which is correct.

If I try to use `localhost:8080/swagger`, I get a 404, if I use `localhost:8080/{controller}/{getaction}`, I also get a 404.

What I have done so far to troubleshoot:

1. I made sure that my IIS USER has access to that folder
2. I have ran the executable in the folder, and the API works fine
3. If I run the API with `dotnet run`, I can call the endpoints successfully
4. I have read if any particular configuration should be done in the code, but it didn`t seem like it

Multiple questions pop in my head:

1. Is there some configuration that I should be doing in the code?
2. How is IIS supposed to run my application? Does it run the executable? Is it looking for something that isn't there? etc.
3. Is there a configuration that I missed in IIS?
4. Is IIS looking for an executable, a DLL?
5. How does IIS identify which is the main DLL?

Is there anything else that should be configured?

Comment: If you only want `localhost` to work , then you chose a too wide binding. And 403.14 is expected because Web API does not have a default web page to show. If you want to troubleshoot that 404 related to swagger, show your source code.

Comment: I see. When I enabled Directory Browse, I saw the list of files in the published folder. What I really want to troubleshoot is the fact that I can't make any API calls. I have 404 on any request I make, whether it's localhost:8080/swagger, or localhost:8080/controller/action. However, if I run the application using dotnet run, these calls succeed. I will share some code.

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After wasting a lot of time trying to understand what was happening, I created a new Web API, the default generated template containing the Forecast controller. I tried creating a site in IIS for that, like I did for my API, and it worked.
After comparing the configuration of both projects, I finally found the issue.

For some reason, in my `csproj`, I had the following:

```xml
<PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
<RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
<PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
```

In addition, my project's output type was `exe` instead of `Console application`.

This resulted in generating a publish folder that didn't contain the main DLL; it contained only the `exe` application and a couple of other files.
When I changed the configuration to match the newly generated API, the publish folder had the same structure as the one generated for the Forecast API.

After doing that, I successfully accessed my website through IIS, loaded the swagger page, and sent requests.

Answer (score 0):

On your application pool -> `Advanced Settings` -> `Identity` add your IIS_IUSRS user. Your app pool then will be running under this Identity and have access to folder.

If you already done that, try to modify folder security for user to `This folder, subfolder and files`